# Is this possible to put animate tag in path tag to animate stroke-dashoffset attribute in SVG images?

Tags: css, svg

Can i put animate tag in path tag to animate stroke-dashoffset attribute?

```html
<svg
   width="210mm"
   height="297mm">   
   <path class="path" fill="transparent" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" d="m 377.53434,303.59156 c -8.85782,-2.52029 -17.15925,-6.52635 -25.10382,-11.12167 -9.11305,-4.57105 z">          
      <animate id="a1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="4000" to="0" dur="10s" /> 
    </path>
</svg>
```

if this is possible why this code does not work?
(A lot of path is omitted for simplicity)

Comment: Stroke-dash-array needed? You might also want to change the stroke to something other than white so we can see it.

Comment: thanks! You right. Stroke-dash-array needed. another question. can i do something like forwards in animation attribute CSS (animation: dash 5s linear **forwards**;) in animate tag?

Comment: fill="freeze" would do that.

Comment: Yep! its done. thanks both of you guys.